# datatype in request parameter $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-framework3, zend-view

so far I have worked only with integer values as request parameters in urls.

Now I need to work with strings which contain spaces etc. for example:
"xyz 666 888-VCT"

I send the route and parameters out of my view script:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url('pcb', ['action' => 'index', 'id' => $rs->Part_Number]) ?>">PCB</a>
```

I try to get it within my controller action:

```
$id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
```

How is the right way to catch a string value in this case?

edit:
here additional my routing paramters:

```
'pcb' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/pcb[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                              'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\PcbController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],

                        ],
```

I get always

> the requested url could not match by routing

My url looks like follows:
...pcb/index/3441 99901 B 03 2519 xyz

I'm sure the problem are the spaces, so my question a bit more detailed, can I quote or somewhat the routing parameter?

Comment: It is `string` by default, isn’t it?

Comment: It might be the 'constraints' key in the route options array that is causing it to fail, integer values would be using something like '[0-9]*' that wouldn't work with your example if you copied and pasted the config from another route.

Comment: it must be string, because the file is imported and this string column is the only identification I get there. Because of law reasons this file can't be changed or get additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
my regular expression in the routing was wrong, I changed it to:

```
 'id'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-\. /]*',
```